# Build issue with the Google Docs Java API

Tags: google-docs-api

I'm trying to get some google docs functionality going and I've decided to do the basic tutorial they provide [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/eclipse.html#eclipse)

I followed their instructions to the T but got the following error when I tried to run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:118)
    at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.<init>(AltRegistry.java:100)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:555)
    at technical.services.getDocumentList.main(getDocumentList.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 4 more
```

I double checked that I had all of the dependencies that were required in my build path, and I know they are recognized in my project because the IDE isn't complaining when I instantiate objects from the referenced API's.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following Jar which is apparently needed but not mentioned in the tutorial.

```
deps/google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar
```